How can I show inline IPython plots?
I want to plot matplotlib figures inline in ipython in the (wezterm) terminal.
In the terminal proper this works:

However, in Neovim, it does not:

In this question I was told it's not possible for a neovim terminal buffer to show images. The screenshot above is ipython launched from inside a terminal buffer, so I guess it's unsurprising that it is not working.
Is there another way? Can I launch ipython in a buffer without using the terminal? Would that work in displaying the images, or is there a similar restriction?
(I haven't yet understood where the restriction is inside terminal buffers.)

The corresponding answer is unfortunately also valid for the GUI version of Vim (i.e. gVim) since the share the same design and the same screen representation.
Remark: That being said the image Neovim plugin that you have identified could be a way go in the desired direction but I suspect the slope will be steep :-|

It looks like magma has been able to implement it. It just doesn't work on my machine :/. Ok, I have to stop obsessing over this for the moment, I'll live with a separate ipython gui for now

(actually, molten is a better and more up-to-date example)
